# Laravel, what is mean variable $app

Tags: laravel

I don't know $app mean and where does $app make?

[image]

Comment: `$` states it is a variable called `app`?

Comment: it means app is project

Answer (score 0):

If you can't call `$this->app->make('HelpSpot\API')` because you can't get access to `$this->app` for whatever reason then call this `$api = resolve('HelpSpot\API')`
It's worded kind of weirdly but I'm pretty sure that's what it means given the context.

Comment: this is a example for variable $app, i just don't understand  what it means and which package is it in